# What is good way to query chaining conditionally in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-5

If I need to query conditionally, I try a way like this:

```
query = Model.find_something
query = query.where(condition1: true) if condition1 == true
query = query.where(condition2: true) if condition2 == true
query = query.where(condition3: true) if condition3 == true
```

It's work well.
But I think that it is a way to repeat same code and a look is not good.

Is it possible query does not reassign to variable per every conditional expression? like this:

```
query.where!(condition1: true) # But it can not be in rails :)
```

I recently started as Rails5.

What else is the best way to do Rails5?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? I do that sort of thing all the time. It is clean and easy to read.

Comment: @muistooshort I know...this is not so bad. I do this way all the time too.  However I suddenly  wonder if I  use the bang method to change model instance that it changes itself even if it don't assign to itself, then why don't I can do with query interface? So I have a question. Why the relation have to assign itself to add some query?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach, you can even skip the `== true` part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use model scopes:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_title, ->(title) { where(title: title) if title }
  scope :by_author, ->(name) { where(author_name: name) if name }
end
```

Just chain scopes anywhere you need:

```
Article.by_title(params[:title]).by_author(params[:author_name])
```

If parameter present you get scoped articles, if there is no such parameter - you get all Articles